# How to print links' href values on a web page from being printed

Tags: drupal, printing, href

I am coding a few web pages with Drupal 7 and 960 grid system.

When I print pages, the links (href values) in these page get printed. For example, a clickable image gets its URL printed beneath it. Links in text get their href values printed too.

How can I prevent the href values from being printed.

I am not sure whether this is Drupal related.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 5):

Found out that these href values are made visible by the Drupal theme I use. Here is how I hide it:

```
a[href]:after { content: ""; /* hide visible URL after links. */ }
```

Adam, thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might work for you, but I haven't tested it yet

```
@media print {
    a:link:after,
    a:visited:after {
       content: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I cleared any system caches and reloaded the page. Unfortunately, I still see the href values printed. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect solution for me. It works great! Thank you Adam +1

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark: Some themes (I think I found it in a zen-based subtheme) bring css-instructions like above:

```
a[href]:after { content: "..."; }
```

At first it's a hard time finding the pattern to search for. Well done.